# How to find the most time cost line when log analysing using just linux command?

Tags: bash, sorting, command

I have a log file with this pattern:

```
2020-02-02 11:20:20 requestId method=someGet param=param cost=100
2020-02-02 11:20:21 requestId1 method=someGet param=param cost=101
2020-02-02 11:20:22 requestId2 method=someGet param=param cost=103
```

How can I find the most cost request, or How can I sort these lines to find out which method cost most?

Comment: `sort -rnk4 -t= log.txt | head -n1`

Comment: `-r` option realldy help me Thanks @Jetchisel